# I was using the python crawler. why cause of outbreak the HTTP 405 Error?

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I am not good at English. So please be good to understand my awkward English.

I tryed using the HTTP POST to crawling Google

but some problem have arisen.

Problem is the HTTP 405 Error occurred in the output page

This is python 3.5.1 source

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def image_upload():
    filePath = 'C:/test.jpg'
    searchUrl = 'http://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload'
    multipart = {'encoded_image': (filePath, open(filePath, 'rb')), 'image_content': ''}
    response = requests.post(searchUrl, files=multipart, allow_redirects=False)
    plain_text = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        return  link.get('href')

def Crawling(target_link):
    response = requests.post(target_link)
    html_content = response.text.encode(response.encoding)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    edutData = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'bili uh_r rg_el uvg-i'})
    print(soup)

iamge_link = image_upload()
print(iamge_link)
Crawling(iamge_link)
```

Why in output page the HTTP 405 Error happen probluem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http Response 405 is returned when request method you are using is not supported. In your case **post** method might not be supported by the endpoint you are accessing.

For reference, [Http Response 405](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)

Comment: @이상현 I hope, you were able to figure out the problem in your case. If the answer helps you can mark it as accepted and close the question.